# Converting Feature Collection of one element (Multi Point Geometry) into Feature Collection of different elements

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

**CODE:**

```js
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
       .filterBounds(geometry);

// TEST IMAGE

 var first = ee.Image(l8.first()).clip(geometry)

// get image projection
var proj = first.select([0]).projection()

// get coordinates image
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj)

// put each lon lat in a list
var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
             .reduceRegion({
 reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
 geometry: geometry,
 scale: 30
})

// get lat & lon
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'))
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'))

// zip them. Example: zip([1, 3],[2, 4]) --> [[1, 2], [3,4]]
var point_list = lon.zip(lat)
print(point_list);
// Create points
var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(point_list));
print(mp);
Map.addLayer(mp,{}, 'All Points')
Map.centerObject(geometry);
```

Here when I print mp it is showing it as a Feature collection of a single element of MultiPoint geometry.

**Example for feature collection of different elements:**

```js
var ran = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(geometry,4516,10);
print(ran);
Map.addLayer(ran,{}, 'Random Points')
```

What I want it is the same as the above one which feature collection of different elements.

What changes should I do to convert my feature collection same as this one?

**IMPORTS:**

```js
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-67.76435852050781, -22.213792811479802],
      [-67.76641845703125, -22.220785143658368],
      [-67.75646209716797, -22.228412744835992],
      [-67.74410247802734, -22.230319580297703],
      [-67.7420425415039, -22.221420792936158],
      [-67.74341583251953, -22.212203596469955],
      [-67.74787902832031, -22.207753698686023],
      [-67.75543212890625, -22.213474969917876]]]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change variable `mp` for

```js
var mp = ee.FeatureCollection(point_list.map(function(p){
  var point = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(p), {})
  return point
}))
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with MultiPolygon geometry.. when i run the above code.. it gives this error: GeometryConstructors.Polygon, argument 'coordinates': Invalid type. Expected: List<Object>. Actual: Feature. .. any idea how to solve this?